# Set id via jQuery unexpected behavior [What I'm missing?]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an iFrame inside main page, and I want to execute a function inside of the iFrame from main page.

Here is the simple function in the iFrame (we do not execute it in the iFrame, We want to invoke this from the main page)

```
function iFrameFunction(){
   console.log("iFrame Function invoked!")
};
```

Here is a code that we invoke by button press in the main page (working as expected):

```
//First I select the iFrame via jQuery 
  var item = $('[data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=16ULIxk0TGTP=16UwzLEkGHjM.0.3:$c233.1:$c234.$slideobject266.0"]');

//Then simply we add an id to the iFrame 
  $(item).attr("id","iframeId");

//Finally we execute the iFrame function from main page using this line:
  document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.iFrameFunction();
```

The problem is if I try to set the id outside of the button press function ( I created an external js file and load it to the main page ) the id doesn't set.

Here is the code inside my external js which is supposed to set the id:

```
//First I select the iFrame via jQuery 
  var item = $('[data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=16ULIxk0TGTP=16UwzLEkGHjM.0.3:$c233.1:$c234.$slideobject266.0"]');

//Then simply we add an id to the iFrame 
  $(item).attr("id","iframeId");
```

No errors and not setting the id?!

Comment: What does `console.log(item)` return in the example that isn't working? Also, no need to do `$(item)`, as `item` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: give me a sec...

Comment: in the example that isn't working: `init [prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "[data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=16ULIxk0TGT…6UwzLEkGHjM.0.3:$c233.1:$c234.$slideobject266.0"]"]`

Comment: in the example that is working: `init [iframe#iframeId.shown., prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "[data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=16ULIxk0TGT…6UwzLEkGHjM.0.3:$c233.1:$c234.$slideobject266.0"]"]`

Comment: So, when is the code run in the case which does not work ? If you just include the file, then the React will not have rendered and the element with the `[data-reactid]` will  not exist. You need to somehow wait to run your code after the React has completed its render.

Comment: @Gabriele Petrioli Using a `setTimeout` fixed that confusing issue.... thanks for your awesome comment... if you make it an answer it would be accepted...

Comment: @SaraRee You really should use a callback or listener to decide when to look for the element. Using a `setTimeout` is good to confirm the issue, but realize it requires a hard-coded value that may not be sufficient on slower connections/computers. I am not super familiar with React but have to imagine there's some sort of `onRender` callback or similar.